# Installing CartoDB production environment in CentOS

Tags: carto

By referring "**Production deployment**" section in https://gist.github.com/arjendk/6080388

I am trying to setup CartoDB in production environment using Apache with Passenger module. I setup proper startup scripts for CartoDB Windshaft, CartoDB SQL API apps and Redis. I have created a production database with rake.

Installed passenger using below commands:

```
yum install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Then followed other steps from above document, and in ssl virtual host have the following content.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ##This for central domain
    ServerName cartodb.mydomain.com  
    ##This for all subdomains(users)
    ServerAlias *.cartodb.mydomain.com 
    # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
    DocumentRoot %SOME_LOCATION%/cartodb20/public
    RailsEnv production
    PassengerSpawnMethod direct

    #TODO later: SSL options

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile %SOME_LOCATION%/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile %SOME_LOCATION%/localhost.key


 <Directory %SOME_LOCATION%/cartodb20/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In *CartoDB Windshaft/config/environment/production.js* changed following

```
host: '',
,user_from_host: '^(.*)\\.cartodb\\.mydomain\\.com$'
,sqlapi: {
        protocol: 'https',
        domain: 'cartodb.mydomain.com',
```

In *CartoDB SQL API/config/environment/production.js* changed following

```
module.exports.user_from_host = '^(.*)\\.cartodb\\.mydomain\\.com$';
module.exports.node_host    = '';
```

Started CartoDB Windshaft, CartoDB SQL API apps, Redis using above setup scripts and resque manually.

When I tried accessing through cartodb.mydomain.com or prod.cartodb.mydomain.com,

I got passenger error message saying I have to `bundle install --deployment`, I run this inside  *%SOME_LOCATION%/cartodb20*

Now when I hit cartodb.mydomain.com or prod.cartodb.mydomain.com,  I get Error 500 page, that too non of the scripts in the page loaded.

Below the error I noticed in *cartodb20/log/production.log*

```
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/front_layout (101.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 279ms
[Rollbar] Reporting exception: cdb.js isn't precompiled
[Rollbar] Scheduling payload
[Rollbar] Sending payload
[Rollbar] Got unexpected status code from Rollbar api: 401
[Rollbar] Response: {
  "err": 1,
  "message": "unauthorized"
}
[Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=e3df1f34-deda-4f20-9c7f-0e9f90ef1e62 (only available if report was successful)
ActionView::Template::Error (cdb.js isn't precompiled):
    1: <%= content_for(:js) do %>
    2:   <%= javascript_include_tag :cdb, :application, :login %>
    3: <% end %>
    4:
    5: <section class="sessions shadow">
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:97:in `javascript_include_tag'
  app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_sessions_new_html_erb__1047976219462445650_23950283400360'
  app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_sessions_new_html_erb__1047976219462445650_23950283400360'
```

I couldn't understand this issue, could someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to assets not being precompiled, which is needed on the Production environment. You can try to precompile them by executing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

on the Rails root.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I run the above command inside _%SOME_PATH%cartodb20/_

got following error

`AssetSync: using /opt/cartodb2.0/cartodb20/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
rake aborted!
Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank`

Full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/i6g1jjXu)

Comment: Even though it showed error, asserts folder has been created with lots of file in it. After that changed a line in _config/environments/production.rb_, `server_static_assets to true` now I could login. Still I have problem with uploading for which I will start a fresh question.